# What to do when sessionStorage access denied due to browser settings

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for suggestions for how to keep my web form from breaking when users have sessionStorage disabled due to browser settings. For example, I get the following error in Chrome when browser settings block 3rd party cookies:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.`

I have two problems:

1. The exception breaks the functionality of my form on Chrome when 3rd party cookies are blocked. I would like the user to still be able to use the form and just use a fallback.
2. My test condition isn't working because it isn't picking up a falsey value so I can't display a message. I would like to give the user instructions on how to change the settings so they can get full functionality if they want. Is there a way to write a test condition for a DOMexception?

Here is the code I'm testing with:

```
// Test if sessionStorage available
if(!sessionStorage) {
  alert("Sorry, your browser does not support session storage.");

} else {
  // Store data
  sessionStorage.setItem("name", "John Smith");

  // Retrieve data
  alert("Hi, " + sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit -** My previous answer won't handle your scenario, hence exception handling will be required.

```
try {
    var storage = window.sessionStorage || {};  
} catch (e) {
    var storage = {};  
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same DOMexception about access being denied in Chrome when 3rd party cookies are blocked.

Comment: in that case, use exception handling to specifically handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

use `try catch`.

```js
try {
  sessionStorage.setItem("name", "John Smith");
  alert('Hi, ' + sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Session Storage is disabled');
}
```